# How to make the content of a IMG tag transparent but not the background of the tag?

Tags: css

As the title says, how do I make an image in a IMG tag transparent without making the background transparent using only CSS? **I have no access to the HTML, thus I can't make a DIV.**

**The image without opacity with a red background:**

```
img {
  background-color: red;
}
```

[image: Normal image]

**The image using `opacity: 0.2;`:**

```
img {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

[image: with opacity css]

**What I want to achieve with CSS:**

[image: what I want]

Comment: please share some code or create a fiddle as i am confused what background are you talking about

Comment: Which background are you talking about - the background of the image, or of the page the image is on? Could you create a mock-up image of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @LarsKristensen I'm talking about the background of the img tag, not the page it's on.

Comment: @GauravAggarwal https://jsfiddle.net/ygtgLkn5/ This is what I mean.

Comment: this is just a image if you apply opacity then it will effect the image. Where did background came from?

Comment: It's not possible to affect the opacity of PART of an image with CSS.

Comment: @nelson2tm Is this what you are attempting? Make the contents of the image transparent, but keep the background of the `img` HTML element with original opacity - so show the blue color, and not make it transparent?: https://jsfiddle.net/vzL88xrr/

Comment: @LarsKristensen No, unfortunately this isn't what I'm trying to do. I've tried to make the question clearer by adding images of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @nelson2tm I'm not sure what you want to do is possible within the styling of the `img` tag itself. But if you can modify the `img` tag, is there any reason you wouldn't be able to wrap it in a `div` tag and give it the same background color?

Comment: @nelson2tm Example (updated): https://jsfiddle.net/jkm1r3tj/1/

Comment: @LarsKristensen As said, I don't have access to the HTML of the page. I only have access to the CSS.

Comment: Please check this:  https://jsfiddle.net/4q4z4vkg/

Comment: @satya Still not what I want to achieve. I want to set the background of the IMG tag only, not the whole body.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

Use the css transparency style to your image tag and not in your div that holds the image.

Suppose you have like this:

```
<div class="img_container"><img src="myimage.png"></div>
```

Then CSS will be

```
div.img_container img {
    opacity: 0.2;
    filter: alpha(opacity=20); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Comment: The image is not in a DIV, unfortunately. It's just the IMG tag.

Comment: Then do like this:
<img class="myimage" src="myimage.png">

img.myimage{
    opacity: 0.2;
    filter: alpha(opacity=20); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

Comment: <img src="myimage.png" style="opacity: 0.2">

Comment: This makes the image and the background transparent. What I want is only the image transparent.

Comment: This will only the transparent the image.you can verify this if you give some reduced height and width to your image.

Answer (score 0):

If your constraint is that you can ***only*** modify the CSS of the `img` element, then I think what you want to do is not possible. Opacity is applied to the HTML element, including its background. It is not possible to set the opacity of selective parts of an HTML element.

If you can use Javascript, then you could write a script that wraps the `img` element(s) in a `div` or `span` element, and apply the same background to this wrapper-element. This would make the same background show, when the `img` element is transparent.

Jquery has a `wrap` function, that can be used for this:

`$(".classToWrap").wrap("<div class='wrapperClass'></div>");`

[Jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LarsKristensen_DK/jkm1r3tj/7/)

If Javascript is not an option either, then I don't see a way to do this with using only CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have access to the HTML, then you are left with the only option of using the new `background-blend-mode`, which you can tweak to approximate what you want. This will require you use `background-image` instead of using it in the `src`.

Another way is to use `::before/after` content insertion hack along with a few `block`s with `background` and `opacity`. This requires a container of some sort, known dimensions of the `img`, and is probably a little bit more constraining.